# How to keep dragged Node in front of others (JavaFX 8)?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to implement a chess board with draggable pieces as seen below. However, I'm unable to keep the piece being dragged to stay in front of other nodes to below or right to it. Left and up seems to work fine.

I tried to solve this by declaring the `StackPane`s forming the checkered background first and all the pieces only after that, as I read Java assigns the z-index based on the order in which the `Node`s are added to their `Parent`s. This approach is reflected below. I also tried creating a `Group` and adding both `StackPane`s and `ImageView`s to it in order to be able to use `toFront()`. Resulted in only the coordinate labels being shown.

How can I achieve the functionality I'm after?

This method creates the board:

```
public Parent chessBoard() {
    GridPane board = new GridPane();
    StackPane[][] cells = new StackPane[8][8];

    // Create the board first
    // (For dragging pieces to work correctly, draggable pieces must be
    // added after the whole board, since z-index cannot be set explicitly
    // in JavaFX.
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            // x and y in chess coordinate system (0-indexed)
            int[] invertedY = {-1,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1};
            int x = col - 1;
            int y = invertedY[row];

            // Coordinate labels
            String[] abcLabels = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};

            if (row == 9 || row == 0) {
                if (col == 0 || col == 9) continue;

                Label label = new Label(abcLabels[x]);
                label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                board.add(label, col, row);

                continue;
            } else if (col == 0 || col == 9) {
                Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(y + 1));
                board.add(label, col, row);

                continue;
            }

            // Cell background color
            Square square = game.getBoard().getSquare(x, y);
            Color color = square.getColor() == ChessColor.BLACK
                    ? Color.PERU : Color.BLANCHEDALMOND;

            StackPane cell = cells[y][x] = new StackPane();
            cell.setMaxSize(60, 60);
            cell.setMinSize(60, 60);
            cell.setBackground(new Background(
                    new BackgroundFill(color, null, null)));

            board.add(cell, col, row);
        }
    }

    // Finally, add pieces to their respective cells
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            Square square = game.getBoard().getSquare(x, y);
            Piece occupant = square.getOccupant();

            if (occupant != null) {
                String path = "/resources/" + occupant + ".png";
                Image image = 
                        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
                DraggablePieceIcon imageView = 
                        new DraggablePieceIcon(image);
                imageView.setManaged(false);
                cells[y][x].getChildren().add(imageView);
            }
        }
    }



    return board;
}
```

This class makes the draggable icons:

```
public class DraggablePieceIcon extends ImageView {
    private double mouseX;
    private double mouseY;

    public DraggablePieceIcon(Image image) {
        super(image);

        setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            mouseX = event.getSceneX();
            mouseY = event.getSceneY();
        });

        setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mouseX;
            double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mouseY;

            relocate(getLayoutX() + deltaX, getLayoutY() + deltaY);

            mouseX = event.getSceneX();
            mouseY = event.getSceneY();
        });
    }
}
```

And here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the cells row by row from left to right. Since you add the pieces to the cells, the descendants of a cell cover the contents of cells in rows above or in the same row and left to the cell and will be covered by contents of all other cells.

To fix this you could make the parent of a dragged item the topmost node in the `GridPane`:

```
public DraggablePieceIcon(Image image) {
    super(image);

    setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        mouseX = event.getSceneX();
        mouseY = event.getSceneY();

        // make cell containing this piece the top-most cell
        this.getParent().toFront()
    });

    ...
}
```

Note that this solution will require you to implement some logic that makes the pieces children of the cells they are moved to and move the pieces to the center of those cells. Otherwise a piece could be covered by other cells, if you drag the piece inside such a cell later...

An alternative would be to make the pieces children of the `GridPane` itself. You allow the pieces to be dragged around independent of the cells anyways;  the association between cell and piece is important for the model (i.e. in this case the implementation of the chess rules) not for the view and usually these parts are kept seperate.